# Application does not alway come to top after an install and start app

Tags: wix, windows-installer, nsis

We have an installer system based on a WIX built MSI. The boot strapper is NSIS. It is just the way things went. And it all works fine now but for one little glitch.

There are two NSIS installers. One for new users. That runs the MSI conventionally so they contract screen can be agreed to. The the app checks for updates and the user can do just that. This is the second NSIS package for that:

```
Section -RA_unzip
    InitPluginsDir
    ReadRegStr $R1 HKCU "Software\Company\AppFolder\Property" "User Directory"
    SetOutPath $R1
    File "f:\cpp\AppName\deployment\AppName.msi"
    ExecWait 'msiexec /i "$R1\AppName.msi" /L* msi.log /passive /norestart' $0
SectionEnd
      
Section -r_name_dlls
    ReadRegStr $R0 HKCU "Software\Company\AppFolder\Property" "Program Directory"
    Rename $R0\libssl_3.dll $R0\libssl-3.dll
    Rename $R0\libcrypto_3.dll $R0\libcrypto-3.dll
SectionEnd

Section -Finishing Up
    Sleep 1000
SectionEnd

Section -restartRA
    ReadRegStr $R0 HKCU "Software\Company\AppFolder\Property" "Program Directory"
    Exec $R0\ars.exe
    Quit
SectionEnd
```

Less than half of the time the application comes up to the top of the Z-order. Sometimes it ends up at the bottom! This happens on my Windows7 and my wife's Windows10. If I run this without bumping the MSI version, (It just quits without an install), then the app window will always make it to the top.

I've even added `BringWindowToTop(*GetMainWnd());` at the end of initialization when the main window is well established and running. And I did think it had something to do with the windows installer being slow to leave, that is why the `Sleep 1000`. It made no difference.

The only thing that is for sure is it happens when the windows installer actually does an install.

Comment: If you know how to write Windows software you could try creating an app that calls GetForegroundWindow in a loop to track the active window.

Comment: Hi @Anders , So I started a console app that logs the handle and window name of the foreground window every 10 ms to a text file. It turns out that our window never comes to the top. And the console was also called with NSIS:Exec.  The console window stays on top. And I can find nothing in the docs to change the behavior of NSIS:Exec. This is just weird for me.

Comment: Hi @Anders and thanks. So I have an NSIS session that just starts the logger, then notepad, then my app. Half of the tries my app does come to the top. The other half, and it comes up under notepad. Last 5 tests, my app came to the top 4 times then under both notepad and the console window the last.

Comment: Don't execute the diagnostic app from the installer, start it first and never let it be the active window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Quit` directly after `Exec` is not a good idea because if the installer quits before the child process has displayed its window the right to set the foreground window is lost.

You could try

```
ExecShell /WAITFORINPUTIDLE "" "$R0\ars.exe"
Sleep 1000
Quit
```

Comment: I'll try it! Thanks.

Comment: I'm satisfied. I just ran it like 30 times in a row and my app landed on the top every time. It worked with a plane Exec.

Comment: It might work with a plain Exec but ExecShell with WAITFORINPUTIDLE is even better, it waits until the child starts processing messages.

Comment: Ok, I will do it that way. Anything to cut down on glitches. Thank you very much for your help.